# $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with the following probability distributions

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with the following probability distributions.

$P(X = 0) = P (X = 1) = 1/2$

$P(Y = 0) = 1/3$

$P (Y = 1) = 2/3$

a) Compute the probability mass fuction of $Z = X + Y$.

b) Compute $\operatorname{Cov}(2X, Z)$. 


For part a, I have no clue how to solve it.

For part b, the $\operatorname{Cov}(2X, Z)= 2 \cdot (E[XZ]-E[X] \cdot E[Z])$, but then how can I compute the expectations?

Can you please help me with this exercise? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hints* :

Let $Z = X + Y$, then image of $Z = \{0,1,2\}$.

$\mathbb{P}(Z = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=0) = \color{blue}{?}$

$\mathbb{P}(Z = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=1) + \mathbb{P}(X= 1,Y=0) = \color{blue}{?}$

$\mathbb{P}(Z = 2) = \mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=1) = \color{blue}{?}$

About expectations :

Consider $Z' = XY$ ,then image of $Z' = \{0,1\}$

$\mathbb{P}(Z' = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=0)+\mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=0)+\mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=1) = \color{blue}{?}$

$\mathbb{P}(Z' =1) = \mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=1) = \color{blue}{?}$

Then : $\mathbb{E}(Z') = 1\cdot \mathbb{P}(Z' = 1) + 0\cdot \mathbb{P}(Z'=0)$

Just simplify $\mathbb{E}(XZ) = \mathbb{E}(X(X+Y)) = \mathbb{E}(X^{2})+\mathbb{E}(XY)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(X+Y)=\mathbb{E}^{2}(X)+\mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y)$

So your covariation $2(\mathbb{E}(XY) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y) + \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}) =0 + \frac{1}{2}$ (because they independent $cov(X,Y) = 0)$

Comment: $P(Z=0)=1/6$
$P(Z=1)=1/2$
$P(Z=2)=1/3$
right?

Comment: @FabioTaccaliti yes

Comment: Ok thanks, and then how can I compute the expectations?

Comment: @FabioTaccaliti added

Comment: $P(Z'=0)= 1/6 + 1/2 = 2/3$, $P(Z'=1)=1/3$ so $E(Z') = 1/3$ and this is $E[XY]$ right? and then for $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$?

Comment: @FabioTaccaliti $\mathbb{E}(X) = 1\cdot \mathbb{P}(X=1) + 0 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=0)$ , also for $\mathbb{E}(Y)$

Comment: But then $\operatorname{Cov}(2X, Z)= 2 \cdot (E[XY]-E[X] \cdot E[Y])= 2 \cdot \big(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3}\big) = 0$ from the solution it should be 1/2.

Comment: But you want to find $cov(2X,Z)$ , not $cov(2X,Y)$

Comment: Oh yes you are right, so $\operatorname{Cov}(2X, Z)= 2 \cdot (E[XZ]-E[X] \cdot E[Z])$, so I have $E[X]$ that is 1/2, how can I calculate $E[XZ]$ and $E[Z]$? Becasue $E[Z'] = E[XY]$, but I should find $E[XZ]$

Comment: @FabioTaccaliti consider $XZ$ and make the same operations

Comment: So $E[Z]=1 \cdot P(Z=1) + 2 \cdot P(Z=2) = 7/6$. right (should I consider also (Z=2))?
I have some problems to calculate $E[XZ]$, can you help me?

Comment: how do you calculate 1/4 in your answer, $E[X] \cdor E[Y]$ should not be $1/2 \cdot 2/3$?

Comment: Because of $X$ and $Y$ - independent : $cov(X,Y) = 0$, but $cov(X,X) = Var(X,X) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: So we end up that $Cov(2X, Z) = 2 \cdot (E[XY]-E[X] \cdot E[Y]) = 2 \cdot Cov(X,Y)$, since the random variables (X and Y) are independent they are also uncorrelated so $Cov(X,Y)=0$, then $Cov(2X,Z)$ should be $0$ as well no?

Comment: @FabioTaccaliti no $cov(2X,Z) = 2(cov(X,X+Y)) = 2 cov(X,X) + 2cov(X,Y) = 2 Var(X)$

Comment: I got it, thanks!